# Entity Framework Code First boolean foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class like the following:

```
public sealed class User 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    [Required] public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required] public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

And another:

```
public sealed class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The `IsAdmin` property of the `User` class signifies whether or not the user is an admin. What I want to do is add a new property to `Group`:

```
public List<User> Admins { get; set; }
```

This new list will contain all users that are admins of their group, meaning that their property `IsAdmin` has value `true`. I have considered using a custom getter for this property, like so:

```
public List<User> Admins
{
    get
    {
        return this.Users.Where(user => user.IsAdmin);
    }
}
```

However, I would like to know if Entity Framework can take care of this for me. In my head I can imagine it using `IsAdmin` in a way similar to how `GroupId` is used for the `Users` list, where every user that has `User.GroupId = "foo"` is included in the `Users` list of the group with `Group.Id = "foo"`.

So my question is, how do I tell EF to use the `IsAdmin` property of users as a foreign key to populate `Admins`?

Comment: You should just stick with the Property `List<User> Admins`. Why complicate this when you already have something that works? Simple is better.

Comment: Since an admin "is a" user, you could use [inheritance](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: *I would like to know if Entity Framework can take care of this for me* The current answer doesn't explicitly state it, but the answer to this question is "NO".

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, using the term "Foreign Key" in this context is wrong. IsAdmin is not a foreign key, at best it is a discriminator.

Secondly, you can use the [NotMapped] attribute like this

```
[NotMapped]    
public List<User> Admins
{
  get
  {
    return this.Users.Where(user => user.IsAdmin);
  }
}
```

so that EF ignores that property and doesn't try to create any relationships with it, That way you will get the values you want lazyloaded when you access Admins.

<strike>Finally, I think you have your data structure all wrong. Unless a User could only ever be a member of one group OR being an admin in one group made them admins across all groups that they were a member of, then your structure would make sense from a domain perspective but still be wrong from a data perspective.
What I advise that you do is view the Admin <-> User relationship as Many to many and introduce an intersect object GroupAdmins which would have the Id of the group and the Id of the user. You can have that intersect table created automatically by EF giving you a simpler domain model or you could do it manually, [See article for the former here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).</strike>

Re-reading, your question, the above doesn't apply, however, I'll leave it here in case someone with a similar situation happens upon this answer.